# How to calculate and chart cumulative flex time?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

Being a (productive) geek, I want to keep track of the [trend](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trend_estimation) of my [flextime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flextime). I keep a personal document of my hours worked in Google Sheets, having one column for hours worked every day. By subtracting `8` from this number I calculate my +/- flex earned that day.

First, I wish to display the [cumulative sum](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CumulativeSum.html) for the total flextime account, corresponding to every working day, i.e.:

```
  A      B      C
1 Time   Flex   Cumulative Flex
2 8.25   0.25   0.25
3 8.5    0.5    0.75
4 7.75  -0.25   0.5
```

Second, I want to plot it, having some kind of date reference on the horizontal axis, e.g. day of the month.

I tried making an ArrayFormula as e.g. C3 `=ArrayFormula(B3:B100-8+C2:C99)` but saw:

> **error:** Circular dependency detected

Answer (score 1):

Adding a column for date and calculating the C values with:

```
=if(istext(D1),C2,D1+C2)
```

in D2 copied down a chart might be plotted of this Data Sheet1!A1:A4, Sheet1!D1:D4 with Use row 1 as headers:

[image: WA17439 example]

Answer (score -2):

Removed previous things as it was going to be a bit messy

So firstly I ditched you `Cumulative Flex`  column.

I then added the panorama pivot table gadget to the sheet and selected the data

The I created a formula using the running sum and put in flex time the result of which can be seen
[image]
[here](https://spreadsheets.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0An0wNJzxkz99dGVzMURtNk41VFpJV3R5Tm1NUmd0ZWc&hl=en_GB)

And a tutorial for the gadget can be found [here](http://www.panorama.com/google/pivot-table-overview.html)

Comment: But wont that prohibit the cumulative behaviour? I mean C4 would depend on C3.

Comment: Yes, the issue is though, that I would prefer to use an arrayFormula to automatize the operation... Otherwise I'll have to copy/paste and increse the numbers by one... Hmm.

Comment: @Theodor see my new edit this one is a really nice solution :)